# Inserting into an SQL Azure database changes the read into variable data for a & character to &amp; in the sql field data

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, azure

Hi I have a field data containing a & character ie 1&2 but when that data is read and then inserted into an Azure SQL Database the & symbol is replaced as `&amp;` so the data is `1&amp;2`  that's crazy why is Azure doing this and how to prevent it ?

```
            strcpy(s, "select ta.Tank_Id, ta.Fish_Id, ta.Date_Assigned, t.Group_Name from Tank_Assignment as ta join Tank as t on t.Tank_Id = ta.Tank_Id join Tank_Group as tg on tg.Group_Name = t.Group_Name where ta.Date_UnAssigned is null");
            sprintf(&s[strlen(s)], " and tg.Site_Name = '%s' ORDER BY ta.Tank_Id", Site_Name);
            sql->exec_direct(s);

            if (!sql->success() && sql->ret != 100) {
                DisplaySQLError(hW, sql, s);
            }
            while (sql->success() && sql->fetch() == MSQL_SUCCESS) {
                sql->get_col_str("Tank_Id", sTank_Id);
                sql->get_col_str("Fish_Id", sFish_Id);
                sql->get_col_str("Date_Assigned", sDate_Assigned);
                sql->get_col_str("Group_Name", sGroup_Name);

                strcpy(s, "insert into sqlazure.ha.dbo.itank");
                strcat(s, " (Tank_Id,Fish_Id,Date_Assigned,Feed,Morts,Moved,Enviro,Weight,Group_Name,User_Id) ");
                sprintf(&s[strlen(s)], " VALUES('%s',", sTank_Id);
                sprintf(&s[strlen(s)], " '%s',", sFish_Id);
                sprintf(&s[strlen(s)], " '%s',", sDate_Assigned);
                sprintf(&s[strlen(s)], " '%s',", "null");
                sprintf(&s[strlen(s)], " '%s',", "null");
                sprintf(&s[strlen(s)], " '%s',", "null");
                sprintf(&s[strlen(s)], " '%s',", "null");
                sprintf(&s[strlen(s)], " '%s',", "null");
                sprintf(&s[strlen(s)], " '%s',", sGroup_Name);
                sprintf(&s[strlen(s)], " '%s')", _szUsername);
                sql2->exec_direct(s);

                if (!sql2->success() && sql2->ret != 100) {
                    DisplaySQLError(hW, sql, s);
                }

            }
            sql->end_fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens in connection with HTML, XHTML or XML where some characters have a special meaning and therefore must be escaped, or you are using characters, which are not covered by the character encoding your string uses.

You'll [find a lot of lists like this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) showing such replacement codes, called *entities*.

Most usual are `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;` but there are many more...

In other words: This is not *crazy*, but a question of **how to read** your data.

Comment: Well it is crazy as my save with insert sql statement puts it in correctly with sql 2106 database engine but when its saved to sql azure it change it so there is a difference in them.. and sql azure is changing it. and I need an answer to m question on how to fix it.

Comment: @RobertPeterBronstein Might be, that your statement is sent within an XML container where all strings **must be escaped** propely. Once again: I'm pretty sure, that this issue must be solved on the reading side (where the statement is interpreted) rather than on your sending side (where the statement is built).

Comment: Thanks it turned out to be in the gridview and not in the database which I am a lot happier about !

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the data in sql azure is the same as sql in 2016 the problem was with the asp gridview its displaying the & and when that is read it in a session value it contains the & I now need to stop the grid from displaying those characters now. sorry for the wild goose chase.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the asp gridview does not display the extra amp; data but when you read it using tankrow.Cells[2].Text; it adds it in while if you use the HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tankrow.Cells[2].Text); it gets rid of it.